# Flash: making a jagged line grow

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to figure out how I would make a line grow or fade in basically, such as in a line graph how it shows increasing growth as the viewer watches the line move up and down and more up etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're looking for? There are many different ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw the line or use an image, place a mask over it and have it fade in (for example from left to right) to have the line appearing to be drawn.

if line is your Sprite or MovieClip:

```
var mask : Shape = new Shape();
addChild(mask);
line.mask = mask;
mask.graphics.beginFill(0x000000),
mask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,line.width, line.height);
mask.x = line.x - line.width;
```

now move the mask to have mask.x = line.x either with an onEnterFrame listener or with a Tweener library.

Comment: How would I make the line fade in while the mask shape is moving across the line?